# HTML5 Pattern to email field

Tags: html, validation, email-validation

I am learning how HTML5 pattern works, and I am trying do a email field validation.
The problem is that when I add the '@' in the pattern, when I try, the field does not consider it valid. If I try the pattern without '@' works perfectly.

Requirements of the validation:

-> starts with 5 characters or numbers
-> then goes an @
-> continuous with a range between 2 and 10 characters or numbers
-> then .
-> must have 'es', 'org' or 'com'

CODE: 
`<input type="text" name="email" id="email" pattern='^[a-zA-Z0-9]{5}@[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,10}.(es|com|org)$'>`

PD: I know the email field exists, but I'm testing the html5 patterns.

Comment: Your example works for me with sample input `foof9@p3n.es`.

Comment: Note: the `<input>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML.

Comment: @Rob right, I will change it, thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

Comment: @JakeGrossman oh,**it works** I were trying in online regex tester surronding  with quotes.

Answer (score 2):

The WHATWG community shared this JavaScript- and Perl-compatible regular expression that matches the HTML5 `type="email"`.

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#valid-e-mail-address

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/
```

Comment: How can I make this compatible for c#? 
With the code above as a matching pattern in C#, using "..." instead of /.../, the \/ and \. are seen as an 'unrecognized escape character', and thus give an error. 

I left the first \ out, and replaced the \. for \x2e. It seems to work well. However, with my limited Regex skills, I hope I don't mess up the pattern now and start to allow incorrect emailadresses. So please let me know if there are compatible c# patterns

Comment: I'm not sure. Doesn't C# have an email validation function? (I'm a cfml/java developer and use the built-in isValid("email") function or a 3rd-party library that performs DNS A/MX record lookups.)

Comment: Ah I got it, just use @"...." instead of /.../  seems to do the job in C#

Answer (score 0):

you can use `type= "email"` in html 5. that will validate email but to validate email on specific pattern you need to write `regex` in jquery/javascript.

https://www.w3resource.com/javascript/form/email-validation.php